# How to get desired output in this loop

Tags: functions, piecewise, sequence, infinite-loop

```
f[today_, yesterday_] := 
\[Piecewise]{
   {+today, (Lo < today < VarBN) && (yesterday < today)},
   {+today, (VarBP < today < VarMN) && (yesterday < today)},
   {+today, (VarMP < today < VarAN) && (yesterday < today)},
   {+today, (VarAP < today < Hi) && (yesterday < today)},
   {+today, VarBN <= today <= VarBP},
   {+today, VarMN <= today <= VarMP},
   {+today, VarAN <= today <= VarAP},
   {-today, (Lo < today < VarBN) && (yesterday > today)},
   {-today, (VarBP < today < VarMN) && (yesterday > today)},
   {-today, (VarMP < today < VarAN) && (yesterday > today)},
   {-today, (VarAP < today < Hi) && (yesterday > today)}}

For[n = 2; H[[n]], n <= 252, n++, f[n, n - 1]; Print[f[n]]]
```

What I am trying to do is take a Table of 252 elements (H) and have this loop take each element in the list (each element labeled as "today" and previous element is "yesterday") and perform the above piecewise function and then print out that piecewise value for each of the 252 elements. My question is whether or not its a syntax problem or an actual programming issue?

Comment: Please give the form of table H (maybe the first 10 lines of H).

Comment: Try For[n=2, n<=252, n++, Print[f[n, n-1]]]  Then try For[n=2, n<=252, n++, Print[f[H[[n]], H[[n]]-1]]]

Comment: F = FinancialData["HD", {"Jan. 1, 2015", "Jan. 1, 2016"}]
H = Table[F[[n, 2]], {n, 1, 252}]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MovingMap`.

First it is faster to get `h` with `Part` rather than with `Table`.  Also it is a bad idea to create variables that begin with a capital letter as you could conflict with built-in symbols.

```
dat = FinancialData["HD", {"Jan. 1, 2015", "Jan. 1, 2016"}];
h = dat[[All, 2]];
```

You have not provided the definitions for the variables in the `Piecewise` but the following will create a moving window of 2 items and pass them to your `f`.  You don't need to use `Print`. Put the following in its own cell in the notebook.

```
MovingMap[f[Sequence @@ #] &, h, 1]
```

Note there is no ending semicolon (`;`) so the results will display in the notebook.

Hope this helps.